# How to customize the preview button of UIImagePickerController in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need a help from your side, Actyally I done showCameraControls = NO; and I had a customized button for preview to th captured video.How to get the previedw mode when showCameraControls = NO;.

Guy's Please help me to get rid of this.

Hope I will get quick response from your side.

Thanks in advance,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.

http://hi.baidu.com/myguru/blog/item/6a16880a0fef121795ca6baf.html

All the best.

Thanks,

Kanji

Comment: Thanks for your link.But its bit harder to understand for me.I am confused of this.can you please suggest me with any other ides?